# Unable to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage using Azure.Storage.Blobs NuGet package

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am trying to upload a sample doc file to azure storage blob using .NET Core (V3.1) console application using C#. I am running console application in Visual Studio 2019 locally.

I had

Step1: Created a .NET Core console Application & Nuget packages Installed

```
Azure.Storage.Blobs
Azure.Storage.Common
```

Step2: Created a azure storage account and container named : "files"

Step3: Created a word/pdf document in local machine.

Step4: Initialized storage connection string, container name, file path

Step5: Code for Uploading a file in Console Application and then DEBUGGING locally to test.

**Entire Method:**

```
 public static async Task upload_ToBlob(string storageAccount_connectionString, string fileToUpload, string containerName)
    {

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside upload method");

            // Get a reference to a container named "sample-container" and then create it
            BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageAccount_connectionString, containerName);

            // Get a reference to a blob named "fileToUpload" in a container named "files"
            string filename_withExtension = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
            BlobClient blob = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filename_withExtension);

            // Upload local file
            await blob.UploadAsync(fileToUpload);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Completed!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }



  class Program
  {
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string storageAccount_connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sghackathondemo;AccountKey=kCzwrMVmG8r4E9d1q9LKA0W8OuCtPp3WWbeBWoMfyW/6idSN0wPPU+QBnBVndAv+v9tS63gcnpUY1R1CnsHB8A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        string storageAccount_ContainerName = "files";
        string filePath = @"D:\Learning\test.txt";

        await upload_ToBlob(storageAccount_connectionString, filePath, storageAccount_ContainerName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

I am neither getting exceptions nor unable to upload file. Automatically visual studio (2019) Debugging Process is getting stopped after **await blob.UploadAsync(filePath);**

Comment: Visual Studio is closing itself?

Comment: Can you please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? Something that can be tested.

Comment: Wrap it in a try catch and see what, if any, exceptions there are

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Debugging Process is getting stopped . I tried with try Catch as well. Nothing is getting in Catched.

Comment: Step through the code - which line is breaking?

Comment: I mentioned after "await blob.UploadAsync(filePath);" its stopping automatically. I tried with F10,F11 as well.

Comment: wrap that line in a try catch and go to Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions Settings, tick the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` checkbox and try again

Comment: Show your whole method, including the signature. Is it `async void` by any chance? Is this the end of your application (ie is it at the end and terminating)?

Comment: Remove throw from catch and try to print error message so it will give better idea and issue to resolve.

Comment: @dotnetstep Tried but still not working.

Comment: but what is error @PavanKumarGVVS. First of all you have to collect the error like what is issue. If it is not doing somethng it throw error and print at console.

Comment: Finally solved it by passing stream as input to UploadFileAsync method. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand why file not uploaded to Storage blob and why Visual Studio Debug stopped automatically.

**UploadAsync** accepts Stream as input.

With below small code snippet changes , its working fine.

```
           // Open this file and upload it to blob
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                await blob.UploadAsync(fileStream);
            }
```

Comment: This is not why. It may seem to be why. But it's not. The reason is because you are not awaiting your method inside of Main, which you need to make async as well. The reason it appears to work is due to in part to the newly added using scope

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes I changed  Main as asynchronous but still the file not uploaded unless I pass Stream as input to UploadAsync.